# Having issue with windows pathnames while using os.path.normpath

Tags: windows, backslash

```
 if msg.startswith("!links "):
        msg = msg[7:]
        self.msg(channel, "These are all the recent links entered by " + msg)

        t = msg + '.txt'
        t = os.path.join(r"log/", t)
        print t
        f = open(os.path.normpath(t), 'r')
        f.read()
```

This code gives me this error:
   exceptions.IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'log\\SapphireLightning.txt'
*Note the magical extra backslash?*

The log/ should have gone to a log\ and not log\\ from everything I have read about how to use directories in windows in python. I have tried to find another way of handling the backslash but to no avail... What am I missing?

Edit: I removed the backslash from the "log" string and now I get this error:

```
C:\bot>ircLogBot.py #FIMOtherkin test.txt
2016-03-05 15:43:09-0500 [-] Log opened.
2016-03-05 15:43:09-0500 [-] Starting factory <__main__.LogBotFactory instance at 0x0225CFD0>
2016-03-05 15:43:09-0500 [-] [connected at Sat Mar 05 15:43:09 2016]
2016-03-05 15:43:10-0500 [-] [I have joined #FIMOtherkin]
2016-03-05 15:43:20-0500 [-] <SapphireLightning> !links SapphireLightning
2016-03-05 15:43:20-0500 [-] log\SapphireLightning.txt
2016-03-05 15:43:20-0500 [LogBot,client] Unhandled Error
        Traceback (most recent call last):
          File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\twisted\internet\tcp.py", line 215, in _dataReceived
            rval = self.protocol.dataReceived(data)
          File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\twisted\words\protocols\irc.py", line 2622, in dataReceived
            basic.LineReceiver.dataReceived(self, data.replace('\r', ''))
          File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\twisted\protocols\basic.py", line 571, in dataReceived
            why = self.lineReceived(line)
          File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\twisted\words\protocols\irc.py", line 2630, in lineReceived
            self.handleCommand(command, prefix, params)
        --- <exception caught here> ---
          File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\twisted\words\protocols\irc.py", line 2685, in handleCommand
            method(prefix, params)
          File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\twisted\words\protocols\irc.py", line 2050, in irc_PRIVMSG
            self.privmsg(user, channel, message)
          File "C:\bot\ircLogBot.py", line 212, in privmsg
            f = open(os.path.normpath(t), 'r')
        exceptions.IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or     
    directory: 'log\\SapphireLightning.txt'
```

Note that it prints properly from the print command (print t), but when it is passed to open it corrupts...

Comment: I think you do not need slash in your code. Did you try: t = os.path.join(r"log", t) ?

Comment: I changed it to just "log" and still have the issue. Here is the whole run of the program.